# jquery toggle() not working with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wan't to be able to "toggle" a div using jquery through a function but it gives me

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined"

in the chrome debugger. here is my code

```
function hide(id){
$(id).toggle();
}
```

I have also tried

```
if (document.getElementById(id).style.display=="none"){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";
}
else if (document.getElementById(id).style.display=="block"){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
}
console.log(document.getElementById(id));
console.log(id);
return document.getElementById(id).style.display;
```

and I get an error that says

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

More info:

I call `hide()` from the HTML, I input the HTML using js

here is the basic code

```
function inputHtml(id){
 var div = document.createElement("div");
 div.innerHTML = '<div id="'+id+'"><div onclick="hide('+id+')">hide</div></div>';
 main.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: have you tried outputting "id" to see if there is a value in there, and it is what you expect it to be.  jquery expects '#<id>' where as getElementById expects '<id>'.

Comment: how are you calling the `hide()` function in your html?

Comment: I added more information to answer jnpcl's question

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to toggle an id that doesn't exist.

But I guess the `console.log(document.getElementById(id));` would show that already.

Comment: @Altimus_fenn: please check again if the id exists and that there are no typos. Unless you have overwritten `document.getElementById` you would always get the object with it. I have no other explanation for the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Answer (score 0):

Sure the ID exists?

By the way, your function is selecting by tag name, not by ID:

```
function hide(id){
  $('#' + id).toggle();
}
```

Comment: Yes the ID exists, I tried '$('#' + id).toggle();' and got the error " Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]"

Answer (score 0):

First, your code should look like this:

```
function hide(id){
  $("#"+id).toggle();
}
```

Or this:

```
function hide(id){
  $(document.getElementById(id)).toggle();
}
```

Now the actual problem: your `id` parameter getting passed in **is an object**, that's the only thing that'd result in the error you're getting with the first version above:

```
Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]
```

`id` is getting a `.toString()` when you concatenate it with `"#"`, resulting in `"#[object Object]"`. Your `id` parameter **needs to be a string**, not an object.